# How to convert recursion into iteration with LoadingCache?

Tags: java, caching, recursion, tree, guava

I completely rewrote this question as the original one was unsolvable. In order to keep it simple I'm using Fibonacci numbers a toy example.

The [trivial recursive cached computation](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/4971686/published/maaartin/itercache/RecursiveCacheDemo.java) ends with a very long stacktrace, just as expected. That's why I'd like to have an abstract class like [IterativeLoadingCache](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/4971686/published/maaartin/itercache/IterativeLoadingCache.java),
which I could extend like [here](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/4971686/published/maaartin/itercache/DemoIterativeLoadingCache.java) by something like

```
@Override
protected Integer computeNonRecursivelly(Integer key) {
    final Integer x1 = getOrEnqueue(key-1);
    final Integer x2 = getOrEnqueue(key-2);
    if (x1==null) return null;
    if (x2==null) return null;
    return x1+x2;
}
```

and which would take care about all the caching and computation without using recursion.

I'm *really* not looking for an efficient computation of Fibonacci numbers. I need something allowing to use caching together with recursive functions, where the recursion depth can get arbitrary high.

I've got already a sort of solution, but it's quite inefficient and very ugly, so I hope to get some good advice. I'm also curious if somebody else needs it or maybe already implemented it.

Comment: Have you looked at Dr. Heinz M. Kabutz' article on [Fork/Join With Fibonacci and Karatsuba](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue201.html). Some of his ideas may apply.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon: Now I have, it's interesting but didn't really help.

Comment: I found this [cache Fibonacci example](http://vladmihalcea.com/2014/03/03/caching-best-practices/) that seems to apply. See the section called "Playing time" towards the bottom. It seems to work by keeping the previous computed number in the cache and evicting older values. The recursive load is avoided by a careful ordering of the statements in the `load` method. I'm not sure if that can be extended beyond the 'toy' example, as you put it.

Comment: @PatrickM I'm rather sure, it won't work (the way I wanted). Simply calling `fibonacciCache.getUnchecked(N)` means you get a recursion of depth `N`, which blows the stack. Apart from this, they're cheating by iterating `i`. What would happen if they just called `getUnchecked(10)`?

Answer (score 5):

Since you've rewritten your question, here's a new answer.

First, it looks to me like your implementation of `computeNonRecursivelly` is still recursive, since `getOrEnqueue` calls it.

I don't think you can use a `Cache` directly, because you need to have 2 steps in your computation: one that states the dependencies for the wanted value, and one that does the computation once the dependencies are met. It will only work if you never have cyclic dependencies, though (it's the same requirement as in the recursion).

That way, you can queue the dependencies which are not already in the cache (and their dependencies, etc.) then compute them in the correct order. Something along the lines of :

```
public abstract class TwoStepCacheLoader<K, V> extends CacheLoader<K, V> {
    public abstract Set<K> getDependencies(K key);
}

public class TwoStepCache<K, V> extends ForwardingLoadingCache<K, V> {
    private final TwoStepCacheLoader<K, V> loader;
    private LoadingCache<K, V> cache;

    public TwoStepCache(TwoStepCacheLoader<K, V> loader) {
        this.loader = loader;
        cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder().build(loader);
    }

    @Override
    public V get(K key) 
            throws ExecutionException {
        V value = cache.getIfPresent(key);
        if (value != null) {
            return value;
        }

        Deque<K> toCompute = getDependenciesToCompute(key);
        return computeDependencies(toCompute);
    }

    private Deque<K> getDependenciesToCompute(K key) {
        Set<K> seen = Sets.newHashSet(key);
        Deque<K> dependencies = new ArrayDeque<K>(seen), toCompute = new ArrayDeque<K>(seen);
        do {
            for (K dependency : loader.getDependencies(dependencies.remove())) {
                if (seen.add(dependency) && // Deduplication in the dependencies
                    cache.getIfPresent(dependency) == null) {
                    // We need to compute it.
                    toCompute.push(dependency);
                    // We also need its dependencies.
                    dependencies.add(dependency);
                }
            }
        } while (!dependencies.isEmpty());
        return toCompute;
    }

    private V computeDependencies(Deque<K> toCompute)
            throws ExecutionException {
        V value;
        do {
            value = cache.get(toCompute.pop());
        } while (!toCompute.isEmpty());
        // The last computed value is for our key.
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public V getUnchecked(K key) {
        try {
            return get(key);
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            throw new UncheckedExecutionException(e.getCause());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected LoadingCache<K, V> delegate() {
        return cache;
    }
}
```

Now you can implement a `TwoStepCacheLoader` that calls the cache safely:

```
public class Fibonacci {
    private LoadingCache<Integer, Integer> cache = new TwoStepCache<Integer, Integer>(new FibonacciCacheLoader());


    public int fibonacci(int n) {
        return cache.getUnchecked(n);
    }


    private class FibonacciCacheLoader extends TwoStepCacheLoader<Integer, Integer> {
        @Override
        public Set<Integer> getDependencies(Integer key) {
            if (key <= 1) {
                return ImmutableSet.of();
            }
            return ImmutableSet.of(key - 2, key - 1);
        }


        @Override
        public Integer load(Integer key)
                throws Exception {
            if (key <= 1) {
                return 1;
            }
            return cache.get(key - 2) + cache.get(key - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

I've run a unit test on it, it seems to run correctly.

Comment: There are other methods to override to extend ```ForwardingLoadingCache``` correctly (and consistently), but they don't matter for the example (```getAll()```, ```apply()```, etc.).

Comment: Concerning "computeNonRecursivelly still recursive", you're right, but it was just an error made when extracting from my ugly solution. The call can and must be removed.

Comment: **1** I'm not sure if there's a way to put more workers on a problem,
nor I can see if two concurrent requests for values requiring common dependencies could somehow cooperate.
It might be possible with a simple rewrite of `getDependenciesToCompute` or not, I can't tell.
I'm aware that this is something I never wrote about.
**2** The `getDependencies` idea is really nice.
I'm afraid it doesn't apply to crazy cases like `f(n) = f(n-1) + f(f(log(n)))`,
but I suppose I'll never need it.
**3** That said I thank you for the nice solution. I need some more time to evaluate it.

Comment: One more problem: In `computeDependencies` you call `cache.get` which in turn may call `computeDependencies` if the key expired in the meantime. But it all seems to be solvable somehow.

Comment: @maaartinus **1** If concurrent requests need a common subset of dependencies, they'll both queue them, but their processing will be one miss and one or more hits on the cache. No problem there, except a few more hits than necessary. **2** If you depend on ```f(f(log(n))```, I think your algorithm is intrinsically recursive and you're going to have a hard time converting it.

Comment: @maaartinus Even if you set an expiry policy on the cache, yes, I think it's still solvable. If it's an ```expireAfterAccess```, I think the ```getIfPresent``` call counts as an access, so it will help maintain the value in the cache. If it's an ```expireAfterWrite```, you could ```put``` the value after getting it to maintain it as well. But anyway, it's still a cache so it can also work when (mostly) emptied, and by processing the dependencies sequentially instead of recursively, even if you need to recompute a value, it should help to keep the recursion level low.

Comment: I read your mails on guava-discuss after replying here, with the example using [Ackermann Function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AckermannFunction.html). What if ```getDependencies``` returned a ```Set``` of ```Dependency<K>``` instead of ```K```, where implementations would be ```ValueOf<K>``` and ```FunctionOf<K>```? Each could then do something different when being processed off the queue, including putting more stuff in the queue in the case of ```FunctionOf```, to be able to compute the function. It reminds me of [tail call optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call).

Comment: See the [trampolining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call#Through_trampolining) part.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT:** changed the implementation to allow for a single computation when the same `Expression` is passed as a parameter in several threads.

Don't use a `LoadingCache`, simply cache the result in `eval` (once it has been modified to use iteration instead of recursion):

```
public Node eval(final Expression e) {
    if (e==null) return null;
    return cache.get(e, new Callable<Node>() {
        @Override
        public Node call() {
            final Node n0 = eval(leftExpression(e));
            final Node n1 = eval(rightExpression(e));
            return new Node(n0, n1);
        }
    });
}

private final Cache<Expression, Node> cache
= CacheBuilder.newBuilder().build();
```

Comment: This should work, however I'm missing the following feature: *"If another call to get or getUnchecked is currently loading the value for key, simply waits for that thread to finish and returns its loaded value."* While I could do some locking myself, this would probably significantly increase the overhead.

Comment: This feature is not documented for `Cache.get(K, Callable<V>)` as it is for `LoadingCache.get(K)`, but since both methods eventually call `LocalCache.get(K, CacheLoader)`, it should work. Not sure if it's a real feature or an implementation detail that's subject to change, though.

Comment: Guava contributor here: yes, that guarantee does hold for `Cache.get(K, Callable)`.  I've [filed an issue](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=1040) to make sure that's made clearer in the documentation.

Comment: @Frank Pavageau: Actually, your solution is as recursive as using CacheLoader. But this is not your fault, I was asking for something impossible: *Asking during the computation of an expression for the computation of subexpressions simply implies recursion.* I need to use some placeholders somehow... I'll come back when I figure out more.